# Rcpp Error: unexpected '/' in "/"

Tags: r, rcpp

I am running following C++ code given in R-studio

```
# include<Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector timesTwo(NumericVector x) {
      return x * 2;
    }
    
/*** R
    timesTwo(42)
    
*/
```

2 type of Error are coming:

> Error: unexpected symbol in "using namespace"
>
> Error: unexpected '/' in "/"

Answer (score 3):

You have

```
# include<Rcpp.h>
```

so try removing the space after the `#` to yield

```
#include<Rcpp.h>
```

If the the file save as a file with the `.cpp` extension, RStudio will invoke the correct function:  `sourceCpp()`.